# cakephp 2.3 getting ctp file from console

Tags: cakephp, console

I am writing a `Console Shell` that saves a file as a html file within the `webroot` folder so it can be accessed by a browser through the URL (i.e. /file.htm).

I want to be able to load a ctp file into a variable, parsing the php inn the process and then save the final variable as the contents of the html file. Is there a set way to do this? or if not how might I do this bespoke?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to manually use the View class in a Shell, here's how:

```php
<?php

// Make the View class available.
App::uses('View', 'View');

class HtmlCreatorShell extends AppShell {

    function create() {
        // Initialize the View class.
        $view = new View(null);
        // Pass variables to the view like you would in a controller.
        $view->set('article', array('Article' => ...));
        // Render the view and store the HTML (string) output.
        $html = $view->render('Articles/view');
        // Output to the terminal for testing.
        $this->out($html);
    }

}
```

To be clear, `Articles/view` is a view file relative to the `app/Views` directory and without the `.ctp` extension.

The CakePHP API has more information on the [View class](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-View.html).